# display image in asp page

Tags: .net, asp.net

i have an asp page .In this page an image control .I stored an image in database in binary format. i want to display this image in image control when page is loaded.how is it possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's another link:

http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=129

However, note that most applications do not store images in the database but store them in the file system.  It's much faster and easier to deal with.